# how to use many pages for one component in ionic 2+ as same like we use one controller for many pages in ionic 1

Tags: ionic2

thanks for reading this question.

for ionic 2+ i have one question how to use one component for many pages.

like in ionic 1 we have multiple pages for registration and we use only one
controller.

Now how to use that type concept into ionic 2.

can you please help me for this ?

Regards
Himansu

Answer (score 0):

In your page's HTML code

```
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

You can add the re-usable component you like:

```
<ion-content>
    <my-component></my-component>
</ion-content>
```